# How to calculate an array of positions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I have an array of lengths `[2,6,8,5]`. I would like to calculate another array which would represent the position of each of the elements.
ex: `[1,3,9,17,22]` where 1 is the position of the first element, 3 the position of the second element

`(1 + 2), 9 = (1 + 2 + 6) … and 22 (1 + 2 + 6 + 8 + 5)`.
thank you for your help

I use this but i am not shure this is the best way

```html
var lengthOfWords = [2,6,8,5];
var subPosition = 0 ;
var positionOfWords = [1]

for (var x = 0; x < lengthOfWords.length; x++) {

 subPosition += lengthOfWords[x];
 positionOfWords[x+1] = subPosition +1 ;
}

console.log(positionOfWords);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"position"*?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please understand SO is not a free coding service. You have to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the array and start with the start value of one and take the last element for adding the actual value.

> ```
> last     a     sum   result
> ----   ----   ----   ---------------
>                      1
>   1      2      3    1, 3
>   3      6      9    1, 3, 9
>   9      8     17    1, 3, 9, 17
>  17      5     22    1, 3, 9, 17, 22
> ```

```js
var array = [2, 6, 8, 5],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(r[r.length - 1] + a), [1]);

console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var array = [2, 6, 8, 5],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(r[r.length - 1] + a);
    }, [1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This code works and seems faster than mine but the plugin I use (ECMASCript 5.1) does not seem to support the fat arrow functions.

Comment: @SylvainParent, you yould take the ES5 version with a standard function.

Comment: Thank you!  its works now I will try to understand how it works